# react-collapsible text in collapsible disappears

Tags: reactjs

I am using the prop triggerSibling to avoid the collapsible from being expanded when clicking on buttons. But somehow the text inside the collapsible doesn't appear when doing this. Here is an example:

```
<div className="row">
  <Collapsible
    trigger={
      <div>
        <div className="col-sm-3">
            Text
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-3">
            Text
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-3">
            Text
        </div>
      </div>
    }
    triggerSibling={
      <div className="col-sm-3">
        <button className="btn btn-success" type="button">Test</button>
        <button className="btn btn-danger" type="button">Test</button>
      </div>
    }>
      <p>Teest</p>
      <p>Teest</p>
      <p>Teest</p>
      <p>Teest</p>
      <p>Teest</p>
      <p>Teest</p>
  </Collapsible>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
As requested, here is the full class. It is currently inside a modal component:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { hideModal } from '../../actions/ModalActions';
import Modal from '../../components/Modal';
import UserCreation from '../../components/UserCreation';
import Collapsible from 'react-collapsible';

const Confirmation = ({ title, onConfirm, hideModal }) => {
  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    hideModal();
    onConfirm(values);
  }

  return (
//remove onClose if the Modal should only be closed via clicking one of the buttons
    <Modal title={title} onClose={ () => hideModal() }>
        {/* <UserCreation mySubmit={handleSubmit}/> */}
        <div className="row">
          <Collapsible
            trigger={
              <div>
                <div className="col-sm-3">
                    Text
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm-3">
                    Text
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm-3">
                    Text
                </div>
              </div>
            }
            triggerSibling={
              <div className="col-sm-3">
                <button className="btn btn-success" type="button">Test</button>
                <button className="btn btn-danger" type="button">Test</button>
              </div>
            }>
              <p>Teest</p>
              <p>Teest</p>
              <p>Teest</p>
              <p>Teest</p>
              <p>Teest</p>
              <p>Teest</p>
          </Collapsible>
        </div>
    </Modal>
  );
}

export default connect(null, { hideModal })(Confirmation);
```

Comment: Please post full listing of the function (assuming it is in a `render()` function)

Comment: I posted now the full code. It seems like the content of the collapsible somehow isn't anymore inside the collapsible but outside to the left. I can only assume that packing the whole collapsible inside a row is the root of this behaviour. But I want to open the collapsible when the user clicks somewhere inside the row, but not when a button is clicked. I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your main problem. It is because you are not supposed to compose some of the jsx markup this way:

```
        trigger={
                  <div>
                    <div className="col-sm-3">
                        Text
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-3">
                        Text
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-3">
                        Text
                    </div>
                  </div>
                }
```

Instead, you should put a variable that represents a jsx component within a `{}`

```
const Confirmation = ({ title, onConfirm, hideModal }) => {
  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    hideModal();
    onConfirm(values);
  }
  const group1 =(

              <div>
                <div className="col-sm-3">
                    Text
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm-3">
                    Text
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm-3">
                    Text
                </div>
              </div>
  )

  const group2 =(
       <div className="col-sm-3">
                <button className="btn btn-success" 
       type="button">Test</button>
                <button className="btn btn-danger" 
      type="button">Test</button>
              </div>
       )

  return (
//remove onClose if the Modal should only be closed via clicking one of the buttons
    <Modal title={title} onClose={ () => hideModal() }>
        {/* <UserCreation mySubmit={handleSubmit}/> */}
        <div className="row">
          <Collapsible
            trigger={group1}
            triggerSibling={group2}>
              <p>Teest</p>
              <p>Teest</p>
              <p>Teest</p>
              <p>Teest</p>
              <p>Teest</p>
              <p>Teest</p>
          </Collapsible>
        </div>
    </Modal>
  );
```

Now if you click on those 'text' div, you will the 'teest' appear

[image]

Comment: Thx for the solution. Help is much appreciated.